# Error on scalatest compilation in IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to compile Scala project which contains scalatest.
It compiles normal on sbt

```
sbt
> compile
> test:compile
```

, but when I am trying to build it with IDEA, it shows the following error:

```
Error:(37, 11) exception during macro expansion: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.scalactic.BooleanMacro.genMacro(Lscala/reflect/api/Exprs$Expr;Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/reflect/api/Exprs$Expr;)Lscala/reflect/api/Exprs$Expr;
at org.scalatest.AssertionsMacro$.assert(AssertionsMacro.scala:34)
assert((ElementMeasures.baseElementDistance(mEl1, mEl2) - 0.33333).abs < 0.001)
      ^
```

for each `assert` function in test.

`build.sbt` file contains following:

```
name := "ner-scala"
organization := "ml.generall"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
...
```

Comment: have checked the sdk IDEA used?

Comment: Yes. `scala-sdk-2.11.8` seems ok.

Comment: Did the problem persist? What version of IDEA and Scala plugin are you using?

Answer (score 22):

It may also mean that you have more than one versions of scalatest registered. I came into pretty same issue with compile-time error on assert

Comment: Used `dependencyOverrides += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1"` to fix this. It was strange: my sbt build worked, but the IDEA build failed - even though I had opened the project in IDEA as an sbt project.

Comment: Just jumping in to add that this can also happen when you have more than one version of **Scala** registered.  Using Gradle, I had to tell my project to exclude `org.scala-lang:scala-library` from being pulled in from a downstream project.

Answer (score 16):

I just ran into the same problem and as Alexey described (he should get the upvote but I don't have enough reputation to upvote or comment - thank you Alexey), it seems that it was caused by having multiple versions of scalatest in my project. I was able to fix it by specifically excluding the older scalatest from the library that brought it in (and please note that the exclude needs to specify the scala binary version, e.g. _2.11 etc.!):

```
...exclude("org.scalatest", "scalatest_2.11")
```

There had also been a warning in the event log before the exclude:

```
SBT project import
[warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions.
[warn]  * org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:(2.2.6, 3.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your IntelliJ is missing library `scalatest`

from IntelliJ, go to `Project Structure` -> `Project Settings` -> `Libraries` -> `+` symbol -> `From Maven` -> search for `scalatest` with correct version

after adding `scalatest` library for IntelliJ, `assert` error should disappear.

This is not a guaranteed solution, just give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, there are incompatibilities between how Intellij IDEA compiles scala, versus how sbt compiles scala. What you can try doing, is ask the IDEA to compile as sbt, and not as it does by default.

In the sbt view, you need to open the sbt settings.
[image]

Once it is opened you can enable the "builds" checkbox. As stated by IDEA, it is recomended for sbt build configurations that cause compilation nin IDEA to not work correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excluding just the org.scalatest group did not work for me. On analyzing my mvn dependencies I had to exclude the scalactic_{scala_binary_version} group as well.

```
<exclusion>
  <artifactId>scalactic_2.11</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
</exclusion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but excluding `org.scalatest` did not fix it.

Instead, I excluded `org.scalactic`:

```
"com.stackoverflow" %% "troublesome-library" % "1.0.420" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization="org.scalactic"))
```

Comment: In my case, excluding both organization names still didn't avoid the NoSuchMethodError

Answer (score 0):

over the years the MockitoSugar trait for scalatest was moved from scalatest to mockito.

In my situation I had this error where I had a multiple inheritance issue where my test class was directly using org.mockito.scalatest.MockitoSugar and another extended trait was using the older org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar

If you replace all the exiting org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar imports with org.mockito.scalatest.MockitoSugar then this issue goes away.