# Intellij sbt and sbt shell behaving differently and causing loading of plugin to fail

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

My project compiles fine from the IntelliJ sbt shell or from my mac terminal.
However Intellij fails to detect project structure from sbt if refreshed using the UI.
Intellij build fails, autocompletion does not work. Help!

I have a plugin in the plugin.sbt file as: `addSbtPlugin("com.my.own.artifact" % "sbt-resolver" % "2.0.17”)`

Removing this, removes the problem.

I printed the environment variables and a major difference was that the following(text in bold) was missing in the IntelliJ log, whereas was present in the sbt shell:

key: sun.java.command, value: /Users/koray/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar
**early(addPluginSbtFile="""/private/var/folders/kz/gyzg5tkj42zfh8y24kw4rnqwbxzvxw/T/idea.sbt""") ; set ideaPort in Global := 50459 ; idea-shell**

### Environment Details:

---

Scala Version: 2.11.12

SBT Version: 1.3.13

IntelliJ details:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020

VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

macOS 10.14.6

Non-Bundled Plugins: Lombook Plugin, com.mle.idea.sbtexecutor, com.intellij.plugins.watcher, com.jetbrains.performancePlugin, org.intellij.scala
```

Comment: You can try one of the answers suggested at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39812037/2359227

Comment: @TomerShetah Didn't work

Comment: Have you tried invalidating IntelliJ's caches?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, a million times